# Unable to access NGINX nodePort service in K8 cluster running on RPI

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi

I have set-up a small Kubernetes Cluster on Raspberry Pi currently consisting of 1 Master and 1 Worker.  I have created a simple deployment of NGINX and created a NodePort service for this.  My YAML looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - nodePort: 30333
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
  matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.16.1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent

       ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
      restartPolicy: Always
```

The PODS are up and running and so is the service

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-5d66cc795f-bgqdp   1/1     Running   0          65m
nginx-5d66cc795f-mb8qw   1/1     Running   0          65m

$ kubectl get svc
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        13d
nginx-service   NodePort    10.104.133.199   <none>        80:30333/TCP   66m
```

But I am unable to access the NGINX from the master node.

```
curl http://192.168.178.101:30333
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.178.101 port 30333: Connection timed out
```

If I try from the Worker node it works fine, and NGINX responds.
From the worker node I can use the IP address:30333 or the hostname:30333, although localhost:30333 does not work!

Connectivity from my Master to Worker seems fine.  I can ping, SSH from there etc. either on IP address or hostname.

Any ideas what I have done wrong?

Output from get nodes -o wide:

```
 $ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME        STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                         KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
k8-master   Ready    master   13d   v1.17.4   192.168.178.100   <none>        Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   4.19.97-v7+      docker://19.3.8
k8-w1       Ready    worker   13d   v1.17.4   192.168.178.101   <none>        Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   4.19.97-v7+      docker://19.3.8
```

Output from describe service:

```
$ kubectl describe service nginx-service
Name:                     nginx-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=nginx
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"nginx"},"name":"nginx-service","namespace":"default"},"s...
Selector:                 app=nginx
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.104.133.199
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30333/TCP
Endpoints:                10.44.0.1:80,10.44.0.2:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Update:
I tried a simple Telnet command to the Worker on the NodePort 30333.  But I get a connection timed out error.

So then, I removed the NodePort service and tried a simple Port forward command

```
kubectl port-forward pod/nginx-545b8fdd47-brg7r 8080:80
```

This worked OK, and I could connect from Master -> Worker via this port.

But NodePort service still doesn't work!

Comment: I suppose that `192.168.178.101` is your worker IP right ? And when you try from the worker, are you using the IP or `localhost` ?

Comment: Can you post output of `kubectl get nodes -o wide`?

Comment: @Crou  updated with the output from get nodes

Comment: @MarcABOUCHACRA:  Yes that is my worker IP.  I can use the worker IP or the worker hostname and it has the same result.  But localhost does not work.  (I updated the question accordingly)

Comment: And what happens if you use your master IP ? `NodePort` open the port on every node. As the [doc](https://kubernetes.io/fr/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) does not say if it's only the worker, i see no reason that the port should not be opened on the master too.

Comment: @MarcABOUCHACRA Same issue with Master IP.  As far as I am aware the NodePort should be on all machines.  Please tell me how I can confirm this, or what is wrong in my Yaml.

Comment: When you say *Same issue with Master IP* does it means that you can curl master IP from worker but not from master ? As far as i can tell there is nothing wrong with your Yaml to me.

Comment: @MarcABOUCHACRA No.  Using master IP or hostname Curl does not work from any node.  Using worker IP or hostname Curl does not work from Master, but does work from Worker.

Comment: Can you post output of `kubectl describe service nginx-service`?

Comment: @crou Question updated with output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after many hours and days I think I have found the source of the problem.

I found this blog:
https://limpygnome.com/2019/09/21/raspberry-pi-kubernetes-cluster/

Which led me to this bug report:
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/issues/4674

So executing the following would allow the connection:

```
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

But I could not get this to stick after a reboot (even using iptables-persistent), I assume as the rules are updated by Docker/K8s dynamically during startup and after changes.

This led me to investigate further and I found information in the Weave network documentation about issues regarding K8s network with hosts that use iptables v 1.8 and higher.  (This seems to have also applied to other K8s networking providers although some of these might have been resolved).
I then saw in my Weave log files that it was indeed rejecting requests.

So by executing the following on my nodes I was able to get this working permanently.

```
sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
```

I can now access via my NodePort between all nodes, and externally from the cluster onto all nodes.

Comment: did that solved your problems ? did you check the ports are open to allow incoming traffic from outside through this port? when running curl from the workder node you would not be able to access to the localhost without port forwarding from the worker node

Comment: @MickeyHovel Yes.  This update allowed me to connect on the NodePort from master <-> worker and from external from the cluster from my PC.